# How to access an object parameter from a hashmap value

Tags: java, methods, hashmap

I am trying to access the accOpBalance parameter from the Account method stored in the HashMap. I want to be able to change this value based on transaction type and store it again. I also want to save the the 6 most recent transactions fot the account but not sure how to approach the problem. I hope this describes the problem well enough. Im still very new to this and would love feedback on my code aswell.

```
public  class BankingSystem{

        static int accNum;
        static String accName;
        static String accAdd;
        static String accOpDate;
        static double accOpBalance;
        
        
        int option = 0;

        static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        static HashMap<Integer, Account> accounts = new HashMap<Integer, Account>(Map.of(
                accNum, new Account(accNum, accName, accAdd, accOpDate, accOpBalance)
        ));



        public BankingSystem() {

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                BankingSystem bankingSystem = new BankingSystem();

                int option;

                do{
                        option = mainMenu(keyboard);
                        System.out.println();

                        if(option == 1){
                                bankingSystem.createAccount(keyboard);
                        } else if (option == 2) {
                                bankingSystem.showAccounts();
                        } else if (option == 4) {
                                bankingSystem.deleteAccount();
                        }
                }while(option != 5);
        }
        public void createAccount(Scanner keyboard) {

                do{
                        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
                        System.out.print("Please enter 1 to continue or -1 to exit: ");
                        option = keyboard.nextInt();

                        switch (option) {
                                case 1 -> {
                                        Account newAccount = new Account(accNum, accName, accAdd, accOpDate, accOpBalance);
                                        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
                                        System.out.print("Please enter the new account number: ");
                                        accNum = keyboard.nextInt();
                                        newAccount.setAccNum(accNum);
                                        System.out.print("Please enter the name of the account holder: ");
                                        accName = keyboard.next();
                                        newAccount.setAccName(accName);
                                        System.out.print("Please enter the address of the account holder: ");
                                        accAdd = keyboard.next();
                                        newAccount.setAccAdd(accAdd);
                                        System.out.print("Please enter the accounts open date: ");
                                        accOpDate = keyboard.next();
                                        newAccount.setAccOpDate(accOpDate);
                                        System.out.print("Please enter the starting balance: ");
                                        accOpBalance = keyboard.nextDouble();
                                        newAccount.setAccOpBalance(accOpBalance);
                                        accounts.put(accNum, new Account(accNum, accName, accAdd, accOpDate, accOpBalance));
                                }
                                case 2 -> {
                                        System.out.println("Please type -1 the exit create account menu: ");
                                        option = keyboard.nextInt();
                                }
                        }
                }while (option != -1);
        }

        public void showAccounts() {

                for (Map.Entry<Integer, Account> accountEntry : accounts.entrySet()) {
                        System.out.println("Account key(number) = " + accountEntry.getKey() + accountEntry.getValue());
                }
        }

        public void deleteAccount(){

                int key;
                option = 0;

                do {
                        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
                        System.out.print("Please enter 1 to continue or -1 to exit: ");
                        option = keyboard.nextInt();

                        switch (option) {
                                case 1 -> {
                                        System.out.print("-----------------------------------------------");
                                        System.out.print("Please enter the Account number of the" + "\n" +
                                                " the account you wish to delete");
                                        System.out.print("-----------------------------------------------");
                                        key = keyboard.nextInt();
                                        accounts.remove(key);
                                }
                                case 2 -> {
                                        System.out.println("Please type -1 the exit delete account menu: ");
                                        option = keyboard.nextInt();
                                }
                        }
                }while (option != -1);
        }
        
        public static int mainMenu(Scanner keyboard){

                int menuOption;

                System.out.println("Welcome to the bank of Cal");
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Main Menu" + "\n" + "Please select option:");
                System.out.println("1. Create Account");
                System.out.println("2. Display Accounts");
                System.out.println("3. Deposit/Withdraw");
                System.out.println("4. Delete Account");
                System.out.println("5. Exit Program");
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");

                do{
                        menuOption = keyboard.nextInt();

                }while(menuOption <1 || menuOption >5);

                return menuOption;

        }
```

```
public class Account  {

    private int accNum;
    private String accName;
    private String accAdd;
    private String accOpDate;
    private double accOpBalance;

    Scanner getDetails = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Account(int theAccNum, String theAccName, String theAccAdd, String theAccOpDate, double theAccOpBalance){
        accNum = theAccNum;
        accName = theAccName;
        accAdd = theAccAdd;
        accOpDate = theAccOpDate;
        accOpBalance = theAccOpBalance;
    }
    
    public void setAccNum(int accNum){
        this.accNum = accNum;
    }

    public int getAccNum(){
        return accNum;
    }

    public void setAccName(String accName){
        this.accName = accName;
    }

    public String getAccName(){
        return accName;
    }

    public void setAccAdd(String accAdd){
        this.accAdd = accAdd;
    }

    public String getAccAdd(){
        return accAdd;
    }

    public void setAccOpDate(String accOpDate){
        this.accOpDate = accOpDate;
    }

    public String getAccOpDate(){
        return accOpDate;
    }

    public void setAccOpBalance(double accOpBalance){
        this.accOpBalance = accOpBalance;
    }

    public double getAccOpBalance(){
        return accOpBalance;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + "Account Number: " + accNum + "\n" + "Name: " +  accName +
                "\n" + "Account Holder Address: " +  accAdd  + "\n" +"Account open date: "
                + accOpDate + "\n" + "Account balance: "  + accOpBalance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, _which_ method do you want to access accOpBalance from? When you say "access the accOpBalance parameter from the **Account method**" that sounds to me like you want to access it in the Account constructor

Comment: Separately, in `createAccount(Scanner)` case 1 you start by creating `newAccount = Account(...)` and you set all of its values, but then you create _another_ Account in the last statement `accounts.put(... new Account(...) ...)` - `newAccount` then goes out of scope at the end of the block and is thrown away. Since you've created the newAccount object you could just pass _that_, like `accounts.put(accNum, newAccount);`

Comment: Basically you'd want to do `Account someAccount = accounts.get(someAccNumber);` to get the account you're interested in, then `double someBalance = someAccount.getAccOpBalance();` This can be combined into `double someBalance = accounts.get(someAccNumber).getAccOpBalance();`